# Using grep inside a which statement (nested grep) in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to implement using which as a nested grep statement. For instance if I am looking for all lung data in a data frame it can be done simply with a which statement.

```
site <- c("lung", "breast", "colon","lung", "brain")

vals <- c(1:5)
df <- data.frame(site,vals)

> df[which(df$site=="lung"),]
  site vals
1 lung    1
4 lung    4
```

but if I want to get the same results with a nested grep statement for "lung" , I'm not getting the second result. Any ideas?

```
> df[which (grep("lung",df$site)==TRUE),]
  site vals
1 lung    1
```

And if I wanted to extend this a bit and assign a column, say 'lung_flag' where it would put something like a 'Y' next to the matches in rows 1 and 4, how would this best be done?

Comment: You don't need `which` at all here. Subsetting works with logical vectors too, e.g., `df[df$site=="lung",]`.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
df[grep("lung", df$site), ]
```

or

```
df[grepl("lung", df$site), ]
```

---

`grep` returns a vector of indices with a match: `c(1, 4)`,

`grepl` returns a vector of logical: `c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)`.

Comment: ok, great. Thanks for this. And if I wanted to extend this a bit and  assign a column, say 'lung_flag' where it would put something like a 'Y' next to the matches in 1 and 4, how would this best be done?

Comment: you should update the question with the additional request. The way to do that would be to assign a value to that column filtered by the condition. df[grepl("lung", df$site),"lung_flag"] <- "Y"

Comment: Do not use `Y` or `1`, use a logical vector: `df$is_lung <- grepl("lung", df$site)`. Then you can do things like `subset(df, is_lung)` which is a lot nicer than `subset(df, lung_flag == "Y")`, isn't it?